# React.js & Django S3 Upload Dilemma 403/Signature Does Not Match

Tags: django, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to have a functionality on my website where users can upload sounds (mp3/wav/etc.) and they will be stored in s3 under bucketname/audio/username/sound.mp3, but I keep getting 403 errors after my django backend returns the signed url. I've configured my bucket in 500 different ways to try and get this to work and I will share my current set up below so let me know if this could still be the problem but at this point I don't know where the problem lies at all. My django backend returns the signed url fine and both urls match but I get this error [when clicking on the returned aws url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BHdW.png) . and this error in the console [which is returned after the get request to django](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lag0Y.png). I've been racking my brain trying to figure out what could possibly be wrong and I've run out of things to try. Here is my current bucket policy, IAM policy, as well as the django and react code (I am using a library called react-s3-uploader).

[CORS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQoK1.png)

[IAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCoxp.png)

[Django (right above is the access key and secret imported from env variables so thats not the problem)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyMGD.png)

[React Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17Rvl.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Apparently someone has had a similar problem using the exact same react component but it seems to be an oddity with s3 .   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848379/signaturedoesnotmatch-error-when-uploading-mp3-m4a-files-to-s3-but-all-other-fil/50625248?noredirect=1#comment88260522_50625248. I am able to upload images/mp4's/pdf's you name it but mp3's or wavs don't seem to work and just give me a 403. Does anyone happen to know why? Seems to be an extremely odd quirk, and I can't imagine you can't upload sounds to s3 as I'm pretty sure soundcloud uses s3 for storage.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is helpful or not, but I had a similar problem that I solved like below. I believe it was because the headers for the Content-Type need to match the file's metadata:

```
def sign_s3_upload(request):
    object_name = request.GET['objectName']
    content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(object_name)[0]
    if content_type == 'audio/x-wav':
        content_type = 'audio/wav'

    signed_url = conn.generate_url(
        300,
        "PUT",
        settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
        'uploads/' + object_name,
        headers = {'Content-Type': content_type,
                   'x-amz-acl': 'public-read',
                   })


    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'signedUrl': signed_url}))
```

Comment: This is how I solved it as well! Appreciate the response though. Take care